# HDF5 Library error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, hdf5

I am using the follows

1) VS 2010 C++
2) Debug Win 32
3) The library from here

http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5.html

Basically I downloaded Windows (32-bit) Compilers: CMake VS 2010 C, C++, IVF 12, RWDI and installed it. I tried to include a sample code in my C++ application and ran into the following

```
***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.8.12, library is 1.8.11
      SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
      =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.8.11
                  Configured on:
                  Configured by: Visual Studio 9 2008
                 Configure mode: CMAKE 2.8.11.2
                    Host system: Windows-6.1
              Uname information: Windows
                       Byte sex: little-endian
                      Libraries:
             Installation point: J:/dev/opt/hdf5-1.8.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have two versions of HDF5 installed and you are compiling with one (1.8.12) but linking with the other (1.8.11 in `J:/dev/opt/hdf5-1.8.11`), or more likely you installed HDF5, compiled your program, then updated HDF5 later on and didn't clean some object files in your project…

First try to *Clean All* and *Build* your program again, it might be enough.

If this doesn't work, find out if you have two versions installed at the same time and remove one of them if this is the case, *Clean All* and *Build* your program.

If this doesn't work, remove all HDF5 stuff on your system and reinstall the HDF5 library, *Clean All* and *Build* your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, I have done all of the above but had no luck with the error. Visual studio doesn't give me a Clean All, there is a Clean that I used. What is strange is that I have uninstalled HDF5 multiple times from my system and installed it back, still to run into the same issue. I really want to fix it though, what should I do?

Comment: What can I do to be sure that I have removed all previous versions?

Comment: Actually I now realize, that I am also using a python xy distribution that has some hdf5 dll's in its DLL folder. I think some python packages include it. Could this be the issue? If yes, how do I diagnose/fix it?

Comment: I don't know the typical install locations on Windows. Take a look at the compile flags and link flags in the parameters of your VS project and make sure they point to the same version. I'm afraid I can't help you any more than this.

Comment: "or more likely you installed HDF5, compiled your program, then updated HDF5 later on and didn't clean some object files in your project"  You are a king among men, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved the issue by using

```sh
conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.8.12
```

I hope this will work with you too

Comment: Isn't conda a python tool?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to show up for only when the application(using Theano+Keras+Anaconda) is run using PyCharm in Windows machine.

`You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.`

Setting the `HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1` suppresses it.