# HDF5 library version mismatched error

Tags: cmake, version, hdf5, mismatch

I'm getting an error/warning from HDF5 like below:

```
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.8.14, library is 1.8.15
```

So, my question is what's the best way of avoiding this? I ideally want to avoid it by building hdf5 again but this time making sure the versions exactly match and that it's not reading from some other places although I explicitly specified in cmake where to look for hdf5 (hdf5-1.8.5-patch1) and even more specified HDF5_ROOT env variable!

I'm a novice in this so if you can give easy instructions on how to do this it would be great. Even a way to specify this flag HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK in build time would do the trick for me too.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [HDF5 Library error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738662/hdf5-library-error)

Comment: Well, I've seen that before and tried the solutions except "cleaning objects files from the project" which I think means deleting config files, right? I'm using Cmake to build the project and have explicitly defined where to find hdf5. This is from cmake log: 
HDF5 INCLUDE PATH: /usr/local/hdf5-1.8.5-patch1/include
HDF5 LIBRARIES: /usr/local/hdf5-1.8.5-patch1/lib/libhdf5.a;/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib;/usr/lib/libpthread.dylib;/usr/lib/libz.dylib;/usr/lib/libdl.dylib;/usr/lib/libm.dylib;/usr/local/hdf5-1.8.5-patch1/lib/libhdf5_hl.a;/usr/local/hdf5-1.8.5-patch1/lib/libhdf5.a
Found HDF5 Library!

Comment: `You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.` 

This seems to show up for only when the application(using Theano+Keras+Anaconda) is run using  PyCharm in Windows 

Setting the `HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1` suppresses it.